# PWA app in Google Playstore is not displaying icon on device home screen

Tags: android, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA app and have added the APK to the Google Playstore as an internal test

When editing the Store Listing, I have added the hi-res icon (512 x 512 32-bit png) and the Playstore shows the icon correctly

When the user/internal tester installs the app, the icon displayed on their device home screen is a box within a box (don't think this is the Android default icon but cannot find it's name)

The app/website also has a `manifest.json` file with the icons specified in and if I open my app directly in Chrome on the device and select Add to home screen the icon displays correctly from the manifest

Why is the Playstore app not displaying an icon? Is there a conflict? Is there anything else that is required in the Playstore store listing?

Comment: I had the same thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the manifest file or the Playstore icon controlling the icon of the app itself, it is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and the `android:icon` property within the APK itself that control sit